# Verificar valor de string

Tags: java, string, scanner

Queria que verificasse se o valor digitado é vegetarianos, e se for, imprimir na tela do usuário é vegetariano como segue o código, porém quando eu digito vegetarianos ou qualquer outra coisa ele alerta que não é.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Alimentos {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nDigite o Alimento (Vegetariano, Peixe, Frango ou Carne): ");
        String alimento = in.nextLine();
        if(alimento == "Vegetarianos"){
        System.out.println("É Vegetariano");
    } else {
        System.out.println("nao é vegetariano");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O código tem alguns problemas. Você está pedindo para digitar no singular e comparando com o plural. E pior, tem que ser com a primeira letra em maiúscula. Além disto você não está comparando dois conteúdos *string* e sim duas referências para *strings* que obviamente sempre serão diferentes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nDigite o Alimento (Vegetariano, Peixe, Frango ou Carne): ");
        String alimento = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(alimento.equals("Vegetariano") ? "É Vegetariano" : "nao é vegetariano");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qczxbt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vezbceaj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/Equals2.java).

As soluções:

- Usar [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) para comparar o conteúdo e não a referência. O operador `==` só compara se ambos se referem para o mesmo local da memória, o que é impossível neste caso.
- Opcionalmente pode tornar a *string* toda para minúscula antes de comparar para evitar deslizes na digitação. Quanto mais normalizado o texto está, mais fácil é comparar. Para isto é possível usar o método [`toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase--) antes de comparar o conteúdo, ou [`equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-), assim mata as duas coisas de uma vez. Assim:

  ```
    alimento.toLowerCase().equals("vegetariano") // OU
    alimento.equalsIgnoreCase("Vegetariano")
  ```
- Opcionalmente comparar com tudo em minúsculo e não ter a discrepância do V maiúsculo e do S no final. Se deixar escrito de um jeito específico, ele deverá ser digitado sempre daquele jeito. Se não vai normalizar, então deve comparar exatamente com o texto que você pede para digitar. Se o V está maiúsculo, deve estar nos dois lugares, se está no singular, deve estar nos dois lugares.
- Idealmente deveria ter uma forma de entrada de dados mais fácil de verificar e evitar erros. Pedir para alguém digitar um texto para tomar uma decisão é pedir para acontecer um erro. Nestes casos, costuma-se usar um menu de opções e o usuário digita um número, que é mais fácil comparar.

Comment: Eu sei que é o pior jeito de se fazer, mas é como a professora da faculdade exigiu rsrs. A gente ainda nao aprendeu este equals por isso eu nao usei e tentei o `==` rsrs

Comment: Mas neste casos não tem como usar o `==`. Note que se você não se importar com problemas de digitação basta usar o `equals` este é o único segredo realmente necessário para fazer seu código funcionar. Claro que qualquer erro de digitação será um problema. Eu vou até mudar a resposta para deixar isto opcional, já que isto não é realmente necessário para a sua solução.

Comment: muito obrigado mesmo xD

Answer (score 6):

Imagino que seja um exercício de escola ou coisa do tipo, afinal, apresentar opções para escolha do usuário de maneira textual geralmente não é o ideal para uso prático.

Como o problema da pergunta já foi resolvido pelo @Maniero, segue por brincadeira (pelo fator exagero) uma resposta baseada na [distância de Levenshtein](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dist%C3%A2ncia_Levenshtein), que vai achar coisas com pequenas diferenças de grafia:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Alimentos {

    //http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Java
    public static int distance(String a, String b) {
        a = a.toLowerCase();
        b = b.toLowerCase();
        int [] costs = new int [b.length() + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < costs.length; j++)
            costs[j] = j;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a.length(); i++) {
            costs[0] = i;
            int nw = i - 1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= b.length(); j++) {
                int cj = Math.min(
                    1 + Math.min(costs[j], costs[j - 1]),
                    a.charAt(i - 1) == b.charAt(j - 1) ? nw : nw + 1
                );
                nw = costs[j];
                costs[j] = cj;
            }
        }
        return costs[b.length()];
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] alimentos = new String[4];
        alimentos[0] = "Vegetariano";
        alimentos[1] = "Peixe";
        alimentos[2] = "Frango";
        alimentos[3] = "Carne";
        String alimento;
        String resultado;
        int distancia;
        int prevDistancia;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite o Alimento (Vegetariano, Peixe, Frango ou Carne): ");
        while ( in.hasNext() ) {
            alimento = in.nextLine();
            prevDistancia = 99999; // Valor maior do que qq distancia possivel aqui
            resultado = "";
            for ( String item : alimentos ) {
                distancia = distance( item, alimento );
                if ( prevDistancia > distancia ) {
                    prevDistancia = distancia;
                    resultado = item;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Alimento: "+resultado );
        }
    }
}
```

Aproveitando, modifiquei o código para aceitar várias entradas em seguida, até que o usuário deixe a linha em branco, e na saída aparecem as quatro opções, não apenas Vegetariano.

Entradas de exemplo, propositalmente grafadas de maneira diferente do código:

```
Framgo
Pexe
Vegetais
Carnes
```

Resultados:

```
Digite o Alimento (Vegetariano, Peixe, Frango ou Carne): 
Alimento: Frango
Alimento: Peixe
Alimento: Vegetariano
Alimento: Carne
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/NDtkAK)**.

Comment: Agradeço muito pela resposta mas somente pela questao do meu conhecimento pessoal pois nao posso aplicar isso no trabalho levando em conta que só tive umas 4 aulas na faculdade hahahha

Comment: @Guilherme a intenção dele é dar uma alternativa para outras pessoas que tenham um problema semelhante possam usar algo mais complexo. Claro que para um exemplo simples não é útil mas é uma solução bem interessante quando o problema exige a digitação de um texto e pequenos erros devem ser relevados. Este *site* procura dar soluções para todos e não apenas para quem pergunta. Nem todo mundo entende isto. Nem todo mundo entende o funcionamento do *site* e que o importante é ter uma máximo de qualidade e alternativas nas respostas.